# Can I optimize this script updating ~6000 rows with a lot of data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, guzzle

I have ~5-6k `$items` that I need to update in the database. Each item needs a HTTP request to get the data from the page. In the HTTP GET request I get arrays that are massive (~500-2500) and I need to insert only those lines that are not in the database. It seems to take a lot of time with my current script (1 item every 2-4 minutes) on my vagrant scotch box.

Simplified example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use App\Item;
use App\ItemHistory;
use Carbon\Carbon;

use DB;

class UpdateController extends Controller
{
    public function getStart() {
        // Don't cancel the script
        ignore_user_abort(true);
        set_time_limit(0);

        $client = new Client();
        $items = Item::where('updated_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDay())->get();

        foreach($items as $item) {
            $response = $client->request('GET', 'API_URL');
            // get the body
            $body = $response->getBody()->getContents();

            $hugeArray = $body['history']; // can be from 100 to 5 000 lines and I use regex to get the "history" array from the body
            $arrayCollection = collect($hugeArray);

            foreach($arrayCollection->take(-100) as $row) { // I take the last 100 since each row = 1 hour, so I get items in the last 100 hours
                $date = new \DateTime($row['created_at']);
                if( ! ItemHistory::whereItemId($item->id)->whereSoldAt($date)->count()) { // Checking if it already exists
                    // I insert the new rows..
                    $history = new ItemHistory;
                    // ....
                    $history->save();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I actually crawl the data and use regex to find the arrays in the body response.
Am I doing something wrong? It takes quite a while until it moves onto the next `$item`.

Comment: You can use a transaction to speed up queries and minimize the hits on database. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database#database-transactions

Comment: Also the HTTP call you're making might slow the process more than actual inserting into the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can provide a simplified answer - synchronous execution, object hydration, and bulk database querys.

Consider the following example:

```
$requests = function () use ($items) {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        yield new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request($method, $uri);
    }
};

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

foreach ($requests() as $request) {
    $client->sendAsync($request)
        ->then(
            function(Psr7\Http\Message\ResponseInterface) {
                // process the response into array;

                return $arrayFromResponse;
        })
        ->then(
            function ($unfilteredArray) {
                // filter the array as necessary

                return $filteredArray;
        })
        ->then(
            function($filteredArray) { 
                // create the array for bulk insert / update

                return $sqlArray;
        })
        ->then(
            function($sqlArray) {
                // perform bulk db operations.
            }
        );
}
```

1. Synchronous Http queries - The above example highlight's some of Guzzle's asynchronous capabilities, while breaking out the processing steps.  The code you linked above is synchronous.  Perform a request, wait for a response, process response, rince & repeat.  Asynchronous Http requests will ensure that data is being downloaded while other information is being processed.  I should note that your results will vary, and depending on your particular use case, may see increased resource usage.
2. Object Hydration - aka what your ORM is doing when you perform a query and it returns an object instance (rather than an array), is time consuming and memory intensive.  @orcamius (one of Doctrine's developers) wrote a fairly technical article on the [subject](https://ocramius.github.io/blog/doctrine-orm-optimization-hydration/).  While this is not Eloquent specific, it does provide insight into operations that go on behind the scenes for all ORM's.  The code snippet performs many of these (reference `$itemHistory`, `$history`, `Item::where`).
3. Bulk Database Operations - a widely known fact is that database operations are slow.  This time is further increased when coupled with object hydration.  It is much better to perform a single insert with 1000x records vs 1000x inserts. To do this, code will have to be modified from using the ORM to using the DB tables directly.  Bulk inserts can be performed by `DB::table('itemHistory')->insert($arrayOfValues)` as seen in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#inserts)

Update: Although not shown `then()` has a  method signature of `then(callable $fulfilled, callable $onError)`. If something goes awry with the request you could do something like

```
// promise returned from a request
$p->then(
    function (Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface $response) use ($p)
        if ($response->getResponseCode() >= 400) {
            $p->cancel();
        }
        //perform processing
        return $someArray;
    },
    function (RequestException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        echo $e->getRequest()->getMethod();
    })
->then(
    function($someArray) use ($p) {
        // filter or other processing
    });
```

Additional information on Guzzle's Promises can be found within the [Github Repo](https://github.com/guzzle/promises)

Comment: Lets say that a request failed. Either I get a HTTP code that's not 200 or I get a response that doesn't have the correct array structure. How can I break the "then" promise chain?

Comment: Updated response to address your questions.

Comment: Foreach `$requests` does not iterate over those yielded requests. I tried using `$requests()` instead and now I get a `500 HTTP`. Would using `new Pool` work too in this case?

Comment: There was a typo.  Corrected.  You could use Pool as well.  It is a great way of limiting the number of active connections your application is making.

Comment: Is there a way of adding `query` to yielded requests? `yield new Request('GET', 'URL', ['query' => []])` does not work.

Comment: For simplicity I omitted the optional "Request Options" array.  You can add the query within the object constructor or you can modify the request with the withUri() method which accepts a Psr\Http\Message\UriInterface.  For reference: http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/request-options.html https://github.com/php-fig/http-message/blob/master/src/UriInterface.php https://github.com/php-fig/http-message/blob/master/src/RequestInterface.php